# Touchscreen tap edits drawing object, doesn't run assigned macro

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, mobile

In Google Sheets, I created a drawing object and assigned it a macro.  When I use my laptop in "normal" mode using the touchpad (or at my desktop using my mouse) I can execute the macro by clicking on the drawing object which is how its supposed to work.  However, when I convert to tablet mode and use the touchscreen, tapping on the drawing object immediately goes into edit the drawing object and doesn't execute the macro.  I would really like to be able to touch a drawing object in tablet mode and have it execute the macro.

Thanks.